# Грамматическая основа предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Подскажите, какая грамматическая основа в предложении: Вот она какая зима! и нужна ли здесь запятая? Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Вот она какая, зима!

Грамматическая основа:она (вот) какая. ВОТ - указательная частица, относится к составному именному сказуемому "какая". Предложение осложнено обособленным приложением "зима", которое относится к личному местоимению, вследствие чего обособляется.

Comment: И даже тире возможно.

Comment: Даже скорее тире: приложение стоит в конце предложения.

Comment: Наша классическая система письма (по  Правилам 1956 года) позволяет свободно излагать свои мысли. Вот пример из Хемингуэя. Название статьи: "Вот он какой, Париж".Далее начало статьи: "ПАРИЖ. После того как хлопнет третья бутылка шампанского и джаз-банд доведет американского галантерейщика до такой экзальтации, что у него закружится голова от всего этого великолепия, он, может быть, изречет тупо и глубокомысленно: “Так вот он какой – Париж!” Чувствуете, какую паузу делает в речи галантерейщик? А в названии статьи это паузы нет.

Comment: Еще немного по поводу выбора тире или запятой. Запятая в этом случае является ОСНОВНЫМ знаком, так как ПОЯСНЯЕТ личное местоимение с неопределенным значением. Тире же в КОНЦЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ, действительно ставится, но это верно только для присоединительных членов с добавочным значением. Или, как в приведенном примере, это будет чисто авторский знак, передающий реальные особенности речи.